# Geany c++, error “lvalue required as left operand of assignment”

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, geany

I try to define mathematical operations in geany but it fails to compile them. For example, a+b=c can't get compiled, but on the other hand a+b==c gets compiled but the result of lets say 2+4 is 0 so it is not right. same goes for a-b=d and other basic operations. When i tried to compile this in terminal the same error was there saying "lvalue required as left operand of assignment".
I'm using linux, openSUSE to be more precise.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the code you're trying to compile ?

Comment: == means compare if right and left is equal and will return true/false or 0/1 depending on language.

you assign from right to left in programming meaning that you ned to say a = b+c and not a+b=c

Comment: a= b+c works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to assign, you need to do it like:

```
c = a + b;
```

`==` is comparison operator. It compares `a+b` with `c`.

For example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 5;
int c = 10;

if (a+b == c)   <---true because 10 = 10
{
    //some code
}
```

Here is a good source to understand about lvalue and rvalue:

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 0):

In a simple description ... an LValue is a variable to which you can assign a value to. So in your case, you want to assign the value of the addition of a+b to the variable c:

```
c = a + b;
```

With this operator==() you compare 2 values with each other. Back to your case
you compare the addition of a+b with the value of c. And if "a+b" is not equal to "c", this comparison returns "false". "false" casted to a numerical datatype like int would have the value of 0.